# Text element background doesn't extend into overflow scroll area

Tags: html, css, background, overflow

I've written some code to compare two text files and display as side-by-side scrollable divs, with highlighting to show inequality. All great, except if overflow-x is enabled, I can't get the highlighting to extend into the overflow area. I've taken a few approaches to the css here, both from my own and solutions I've found searching here. None worked.

**inline-block:**

```
#leftFile pre, #rightFile pre {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**float:**

```
#leftFile pre, #rightFile pre {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100%
    float: left;
}
```

**table-row:**

```
#leftFile pre, #rightFile pre {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
}
```

None of which work. The first two only extend the `<pre>` elements with text that expand into overflow, I'd like all elements to extend to the longest one.

The third one is close. But blank lines are removed, and the second column doesn't take up 100% of the container, even when I specify min-width to 100%.

Plnkr with all three scenarios:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hsjnLRlhROCdDzG4GvRa?p=preview

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are not using a list (ul)?

Comment: @Gacci no reason in particular, just thought it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Gacci that did it I think. Wrapped everything in a list and using my css on that. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you are forcing the contents in each cell not to wrap to the next line. This causes the cells to force their width to whatever is needed!

Comment: Great! Also make sure that if you are using <pre>, this is what you are looking for. I don't really see why you would use pre. You could use <ul>, <li>, and <label> if necessary.

Comment: @Gacci I chose <pre> because I want to keep the extra spacing (i.e., when comparing, if the lines only diff by an inserted space or indentation, I don't count as a true diff). I could use white-space style to fix this in a <li> - but what advantage does this have? Is <pre> discouraged?

Answer (score 0):

Your third solution works when adding this CSS rule in the case you don't have the space character between the `<pre> </pre>` tags.

```
#leftFile3 pre:empty:after, #rightFile3 pre:empty:after {
content: '.';
visibility: hidden;
}
```

If these spaces are mandatory use

```
#leftFile3 pre:after, #rightFile3 pre:after {
content: '.';
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this fixes the missing blank lines (they are mandatory in this application), but my second column still doesn't stretch to fill. You may need to expand the Plunker view to see.

Either way Gacci's solution with wrapping all the elements within a list is working and I think I prefer that to some extra .css rules.

Comment: Second column streches correctly in FF for me. But I agree using the correct HTML tags is, when possible, the best practice.